# what is wron in this code using static php variables

Tags: php, variables, static

I want to use this code:

```
class ClsCreateElements{
  //protected $mConnPer;
  public static $mConnMy;
  public function __construct(){
    //echo("CLSCreateElements");
    //$this->mConnPer = odbc_connect("LDVS","","") or die ("LDVS-Verbindung fehlegschagen");
    self::$mConnMY =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lafuwa") or die ("MYSQL-Verbindung fehlgeschagen");
  } 
}
```

When I run the code I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: ClsCreateElements::$mConnMY in C:\xampp\htdocs\LDVS\php\classes\clsCreateElements.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\LDVS\php\ajax\newCustomer.php(6): ClsCreateElements-&gt;__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\LDVS\php\classes\clsCreateElements.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. `$mConnMY` should be `$mConnMy`. Static variables in PHP are case-sensitive.

Your declaration:

```
public static $mConnMy;
```

Your accessor:

```
self::$mConnMY = ...
```

Use `self::$mConnMy = ...` instead.